# Deployment Groups ion TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

Do you need an agent for deployment group tfs 2018 or is it best practice to have a separate agent to deal with deployment to the different environments?

Comment: It depends on a huge number of factors. Do you need an agent to use deployment groups? Yes, that's what a deployment group is: a special grouping of agents installed on target servers. Should you use deployment groups? Depends. Start by reading the documentation on deployment groups and see if that answers your question.

Comment: thanks you Daniel Mann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Deployment Group is not a real group/agent/machine. It is **a logical set of deployment target machines** that have agents installed on each one.

Deployment groups represent the physical environments; for example, "Dev", "Test", "UAT", and "Production". In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.

> Some advantage when using Deployment groups:
>
> - Specify the security context and runtime targets for the agents. As    you create a deployment group, you add users and give them
>     appropriate permissions to administer, manage, view, and use the
>     group.
> - Let you view live logs for each server as a deployment takes place,    and download logs for all servers to track your deployments down to
>     individual machines.
> - Enable you to use machine tags to limit deployment to specific sets    of target servers.

As for using deployment group or separate agents with deployment to the different environments, it's based on your environment and team's decision.

More details about Deployment groups in TFS, please take a look at our [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).